# I get a Flutter import error and I don't know how to fix it

Tags: flutter, dart, import, figma

I have an import error. I already install Flutter, after I run flutter demo it still works. But when I convert file Flutter from web that convert Figma to Flutter this import starts to error:

[image]

How can I get it to work?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:myapp/utils.dart';
import 'package:myapp/page-1/iphone-14-pro-max-6.dart';
```

and the error are

- Unused import: 'package:flutter/gestures.dart'.
  Try removing the import directive.
- Unused import: 'dart:ui'.
  Try removing the import directive.
- Unused import: 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart'.
  Try removing the import directive

Comment: DO a ```flutter clean``` and ```flutter pub get``` and run the app again.

Comment: Please add the error into your question as text. Images of text don't work so well with clipboards, screen readers, and search engine robots.

Comment: so this is the errors
Unused import: 'package:flutter/gestures.dart'.
Try removing the import directive.
Unused import: 'dart:ui'.
Try removing the import directive
Unused import: 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart'.
Try removing the import directive.
Unused import: 'package:myapp/utils.dart'.
Try removing the import directive.

Answer (score 1):

Did you run `flutter clean && flutter pub get` And if you already run it then try run `flutter analyze` in terminal to the location of your project to check is error only showing in ide or that is an flutter error